# Sharepoint issue list adding todays date based on choice in other column?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-enterprise

I have an issue list with a number of columns.

I would like to add a column that is blank in all cases except when a specific option is chosen in a column of choices. Then I would like to add todays date.

The background to this is that I want to automatically add a time stamp when a task is completed and a report has been written, which is the option that can be chosen in the list of choices "Completed task with written report"

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You could create a calculated column as previously suggested, but you cannot use [today] there. You could use the modified column to get this information, but this would change the value every time the item was modified to the new date of modification (not just if the modification was the specific case you wanted).

However, all of this could easily be done using a workflow in SharePoint Designer. Just setup the condition and then use the Update List Item action to set the column.

**Condition:** `If current item field equals value` AND `If current item field equals value`

**Action:** `Update List Item`

Do something like this:
[image]

The extra condition is to ensure that you only update the status column the first time the item is modified to match your condition.

Answer (score 0):

Hi have you tried Calculated column? Add one calculated column with formula :

```
=IF([Name of Report Dropdown Field]="Your Option", "Completed task with written report", "")
```

this should serve your purpose, otherwise you may go for workflow

Comment: =IF([Name of Report Dropdown Field]="Your Completed task with written report", [Today], "") I tried this, but I do not get it to work, I think it is the [today]-part that is not working

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to do this within SharePoint Designer. Create a Data View webpart of the list and then add another cell to the end of the row manually using HTML. Within that cell, add a DIV tag (so you can easily apply conditional formatting to it) and within the DIV tag, insert the XSLT for 'Today'. You can then apply conditional formatting to that cell to hide or show whenever a condition is met.